# Tablet showing 0 internal storage even after flashed

Tags: rom-flashing, internal-storage, tablet

My Envizen V917G just shut down one day and restarted with the factory reset.

I have since flashed it with the software from their website (several times, it fails to format the cache in the automatic mode but claims to be successful if I do it manually) but it still shows 0 space available and it won't shut down on it's own but I presume that is because it can't save any settings since it says it has no space and it restarts in it's factory setup state every time.

Anyone know of any other software I could flash it with to get it working properly, or other things I could try? Or is it just a useless toy now?

This was a gift and I can't claim the guarantee without a receipt and the original serial number intact, which was just a sticker that rolled off the back after 4 months of use.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - **I don't have enough reputation** to place **comments** - so here is a suggestion.

I have been looking around and found a blog from a user with the same device who has rooted it successfully [here](http://androidxda.com/download-root-genius).
Plus the comment from a user [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/410785-need-help-rooting-envizen-tablet.html).

I suggest to get your device rooted and then install (clear some temp files before installing if you can) the disk utility from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en)

From the app, you can see where your data is being used.

PS: You don't necessary need root privileges to get this utility working. However, I am presuming you have flashed the device perhaps to death and may have lot of old data which may be stored from within the system data part of your Android device.

Answer (score 0):

*Here is what is happening:*

The update somehow unmounted and mounted partitions improperly.

You will have to install (flash) custom recovery (TWRP,  CWM, or other).
Go into the *mount* option to toggle settings.
I don't know exactly which partition *(I think it was `/data`?)* got mounted or unmounted, so I can't help you there. But I had the same problem when I got an update on my Acer ICONIA a500. My 16gb turned into 1.2Gb! It took a little bit, but finally got it figured out.
Good luck!